# How to get yesterday's date in Epoch time? [python]

Tags: python, date, unix-timestamp, epoch, strftime

I can easily get the yesterday date like this:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
yesterday = datetime.now() - timedelta(1)
x= datetime.strftime(yesterday, '%Y-%m-%d')
```

How can I do the same for Unix Epoch time?
I tried this:

```
>>> x=(datetime.now() - timedelta(1)).strftime('%Y, %m, %d')
>>> print(x)
2021, 12, 26
>>> datetime = datetime.date(x)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)
```

I could go now to some crazy conversions, to convert str to int and so on, but that really seems like complete overkill.
Recon, there's gotta be a simpler way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: I fail to see anything related to epoch time in your current code. Please clarify what you are trying to do exactly.

Comment: Hey @ThierryLathuille , you can see the answer below. That I did with standard date format in my example, I want to do the same but with Epoch time. 
I want to get epoch time of yesterday, in a simple and reliable way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could use [`datetime.timestamp()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.timestamp):

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

yesterday = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=1)
print(f'{yesterday=:%Y-%m-%d}')
yesterday_timestamp = yesterday.timestamp()
print(f'{yesterday_timestamp=}')
```

**Example Output:**

```
yesterday=2021-12-26
yesterday_timestamp=1640521058.458582
```